inject a datasouce in quarkus
Below is my version info
<compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version><br>
<maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release><br>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding><br>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding><br>
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id><br>
<quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id><br>
<quarkus.platform.version>3.13.3</quarkus.platform.version>

I want to only inject a datasouce in my DAO and get the data manually..but it always showed the exception [ jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.sql.DataSource and qualifiers ]
I have added the DB definition on the application.properties.
Below the the code
The java source
@Inject
DataSource dataSource;

The properties
quarkus.datasource.enabled=true
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=xxxxxx:5432/xxxxx
quarkus.datasource.username=xxxxx
quarkus.datasource.password=xxxxx
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=1
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=5

The pom.xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

I saw lots of examples with hibernate but I want to avoid it..is that possible?

Can you please improve the formatting of the question?

You need quarkus-agroal because Quarkus uses it alongside Vertx to implement JDBC. What you injected integrates Postgres datasource that is configured in your application.properties with the Quarkus ecosystem, and will not work without the actual dependency that handles the connections and queries.
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>

